# Proving the following theorem by induction

Tags: induction, arithmetic

Let $\sigma$ denote a function whose input is an integer and output the parity of the integer.

Theorem: $$\sigma(|||||x_0 - x_1| - x_2|  - x_3| - x_4| \cdots |- x_n|) = \sigma(x_0 - x_1 - x_4  - \cdots - x_n)$$

That's a theorem I came up with to prove another theorem. I can't find a clean way to prove this by induction. Probably there is a better way to set up this theorem.

Also what is the best way to cite in your proof a theorem which is a helper to prove the main theorem?. Proposition?

Comment: Can you prove the base case of the induction? Something like $\sigma(|x - y|) = \sigma(x-y)$? If so, then for the inductive step you can substitute $|x_n-x_{n+1}|$ for $x$ and $x_{n+2}$ for $y$ on the left and similarly on the right.